# How return works in recursion call in python?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

I've written a python function to reverse a list, here are the two functions and their respective outputs.

**Function 1**

```
a=[1,5]
def rev(k,i):
    
    if i==len(k)-1:
        print("in base case {}".format(i))
        print(a[i])
        print("Return from base case")
    else:
        print("in else before recur call  {}".format(i))
        *return* rev(k,i+1)
        print("in else after recur call  {}".format(i))
        print(a[i])
rev(a,0)
```

**Output (Function 1)**

```
in else before recur call  0
in base case 1
5
Return from base case
```

**Function 2**

```
a=[1,5]
def rev(k,i):
    
    if i==len(k)-1:
        print("in base case {}".format(i))
        print(a[i])
        print("Return from base case")
    else:
        print("in else before recur call  {}".format(i))
        rev(k,i+1)
        print("in else after recur call  {}".format(i))
        print(a[i])
rev(a,0)
```

**Outupt (Function 2)**

```
in else before recur call  0
in base case 1
5
Return from base case
in else after recur call  0
1
```

In the "Function 2", when I remove *return* from *else call* and directly call the recursion function, it worked.
But,why didnt it worked in first code?

In Sum of list using recursion, when we recurse we use *return*, so why we not using *return* here.

```
def getSum(piece):
    if len(piece)==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return piece[0] + getSum(piece[1:]) 
print getSum([1, 3, 4, 2, 5])
```

Comment: Both of your snippets do not reverse the list, they just print its content in reverse order - VERY big difference.

Comment: In your first snippet, all the code after the return statement is unreachable.

Answer (score 2):

Function calls and return works the same way for every function. Python (and most other programming languages) do **not** give any special treatment to any function.

A function will follow the path from first line and so on until it either is no more lines and you can think of it as a `return None` or it hits a `return` and it will return whatever the argument is back the the callee.  The second example doesn't return so it continues until all the functions lines are executed. The first has 2 lines of dead code after the `return` that will never ever be executed and are there just to confuse readers.

`print("in else before recur call  {}".format(i))` does the same. It will enter the `print` function and you don't really know if `print` is recursive or not and it really doesn't matter. The only thing that matters is that once it has done its thing it returns and you continue on the next line.

Often you see people doing sillly mistakes like thinking that only the base case, which stops the recursion, needs to return its value, like in this bad code:

```
def has_odd(arr):
  if not arr:
     return False
  elif arr[0] % 2 == 1:
     return True
  else: 
     has_odd(arr[1:]) # The result is not returned
     

has_odd([])     # => False
has_odd([3])    # => True
has_odd([2, 3]) # => None
```

So whats happening in the last example. Well it recurses and returns True back to the first `has_odd` which does not do anything with the result and it hits the invisible `return None` in the end of the function. The `return` only works one level! since it doesn't really matter that it calls itself or anything else. Correct version is with a `return`:

```
def has_odd(arr):
  if not arr:
     return False
  elif arr[0] % 2 == 1:
     return True
  else: 
     return has_odd(arr[1:]) # return the result from the recursion
     

has_odd([])     # => False
has_odd([3])    # => True
has_odd([2, 3]) # => True
```

As with this example your `getSum` you will get errors since instead of results you get `None` if you try removing the `return` form one of the paths and then `+` will complain that `None` is not a number that can be added.